# Accessing a .NET web service via Android using JSON

Tags: android, web-services, json, .net-3.5

I am a seasoned ASP.NET developer but a novice Android developer who is just getting started.

The first page in my new app is a login page.  I would like to pass a username and password to my web service authentication method from my android app.  I would like to employ JSON since, from what I've read, would be the most simple and clean method of transmitting data to a mobile device.

I've been searching around and trying to find sample code or syntax that would show me how to accomplish this but it's been difficult.

Comment: Are you looking for client code or server code?

Comment: client code for android.  I'm pretty sure the web service is good to go.  I just added the following line to the method: <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=True)> _

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice example exactly how to do it: http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html

It is an easy solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing you need to know 
http://android.programmerguru.com/android-json-web-service-tutorial/
and try this also 
http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/
Hope this will help you :)